# How to make a picture responsive in a slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a slider from a bootstrap.
So I added some pictures in the slider but they are not responsive, How can i make them responsive?

```
  <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
       <p>Kledingwinkel(Dronten)</p>
        </div>
      <img src="switch/2.jpg" alt="robot"  width="300" height="200px" class="homeImg">
    </div>
```

I have nothing in the class "homeIMG" 
but the width "300px" height="200px" is also not working... the image stays te same... what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `height` and `width` attributes of the `img` tag should not contain any unit, only a number. But don't use them if you want something responsive, and avoid using both in general.

Use css attributes with % such as :

```
img {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
}
```

Or

```
  img {
        width: 100%;
  }
```

Also, include a JSFiddle if you want to show your problem, so it's easier to understand what you want exactly

Answer (score 0):

Add the `img-resonsive` class to the image tag.

```
<img src="switch/2.jpg" alt="robot" class="homeImg img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to remove the width/height declarations from your  tag. Instead you can set the width of the image to be 100%.

You'll want to set the parent item to be `position:relative;` so the images size is contained by the slider item (note if your item class already has `position:absolute` then it wont be necessary to add `position:relative`)

If you dont want your image to appear any bigger than a certain size, you can set the max-width property.

```
    .item{
     position:relative;
    }
    .homeImg{
      width:100%;
      max-width:500px; /*this can also be percentages*/
      max-height:300px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the image responsive while you're specifying fixed width and height.

Use CSS for responsive layout.

```css
.homeImg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
       <p>Kledingwinkel(Dronten)</p>
        </div>
      <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="robot"  class="homeImg">
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7r3t9es/)